# Calling HtmlPage.PopupWindow from ChildWindow.Closed event

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

Context:
Silverlight 5, 64 bit, Win7, VS2010

Expected: a new Browser Window/Tab opens up for the url passed in.
Actual: no new browser window ot tab appears.

Code Sample: (called from ViewModel.  The View is a sdk:ChildWindow.

```
AddRelatedIssueDialog dialog = new AddRelatedIssueDialog();
                dialog.Closed +=

                    (s1, e1) =>
                    {
                        if (dialog.DialogResult.HasValue && dialog.DialogResult.Value)
                        {
                            var window = HtmlPage.PopupWindow("www.goole.com", "_blank", null);
                        }
                    };

                dialog.Show();
```

We have also tried Prism events to do the same thing but with no joy...
Also have included the   on the control host - but again no luck.

Any help much appreciated:
Cheers,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("www.google.com"), "_blank");
```

It works for me :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, did you try this inside of a dialog event like above code?